# Launch a specific Spring Boot service from a codebase containing several

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am developing an application which will consist of a number of services that will communicate via RESTful APIs. Each service will be deployed in its own docker container and there will be only one service per container. The provisioning and deployment of the container is outside the scope of this question.

Spring Boot is being employed to provide the RESTful service capabilities. The service code is annotated with `org.springframework.stereotype.Service` and corresponding controller code is annotated with `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController`.

Currently, there are three services, one that behaves more as a client, since it calls the other two. They are all annotated as `@Service`, although the client has no controller. More services are likely to be added in the future. All of this code is contained within a single project.

When I launch the application, all three services are automatically started. This is fine for development testing purposes, but I need a way to launch a specific service and only that service.

What methods are there to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Profiles allow you to create instances of projects that only use certain configurations https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

annotating a controller and service with `@Profile("A")` will have spring startup with those classes only if you include that in your running configuration which can be setup for each docker image

Comment: This seems promising. It looks that I have to carefully annotate related classes (e.g. the service and its controller) used by a specific service with the `@Profile` annotation to ensure something is included only where I need it. Is that how it should be done?

Comment: Yes. You only need to annotate classes specific to that profile.  For example, you don't need to annotate a util class if its used for every profile.  leaving it without the annotation will add it to the application context in the normal spring way.